# What is the limit of the series (summation) of the q-Pochhammer symbol or the ~q-Pochhammer symbol?

Tags: convergence-divergence, summation, products, pochhammer-symbol

I am interested in knowing if the following series converges or not:

\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \prod_{i=1}^n \left(1-e^{-\sqrt{i}} \right) \qquad Expression \; 1
\end{equation}

If that is not well-known, then can someone please tell me something about the converges of

\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \prod_{i=1}^n \left(1-e^{-i} \right) \qquad Expression \; 2
\end{equation}

If that is not well-known, then can someone please tell me something about

\begin{equation}
 \prod_{i=1}^n \left(1-e^{-i} \right) \qquad Expression \; 3
\end{equation}

For instance, is there an analytical expression $F(i)$ which I can relate to expression 3 and, hopefully, work with in determining the converging properties of Expression 2 ?

I already know that expression 3 is a particular case of the q-Pochhammer symbol. I also know it can be related with the Lambert series (whos properties I;m not familiar with). That's basically all I know.
Cheers!

Comment: The sums are divergent as the terms do not tend to zero. If they did, it would imply that one of the $(1-e^i)$ expressions would be zero which is clearly not the case.

Comment: Well, the thing is that if you replace $(1-e^{-i})$ by $(1-e^{-a})$ where $a=const>0$, the sums converge (its the geometrical series). However, $(1-e^{-a})$ is never zero, but $(1-e^{-a})^n$ does go to zero as $n$ tends to infinity. Now, in the case which I;m  asking $\prod (1-e^{-i})<1$ but I don't know if in the limit this product goes to zero.
Thus, @aleden, if you're sure of what you're saying, please elaborate. Thnx

Comment: It seems that, as a very first approximation, $\sum_{n=1}^{p} \prod_{i=1}^n \left(1-e^{-i} \right)\sim \frac p 2 $. For $p=10^3$, the summation is $\approx 504.622$ and for $p=10^4$, it is $\approx 5044.48$

Answer (score 0):

I will take this opportunity to share some of the cooler things about [elementary symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial) which seem to apply in this case. Let's forgo the considerations of convergence for the moment, and consider these products symbolically as polynomial expansions in some auxiliary $x$. For your third expression, suppose more generally that we are looking at products of the form 
$$E_n(x) := \prod_{1 \leq i \leq n} \left(1 - e^{f(i)} x\right).$$ Then we can expand these products for $x_j := e^{f(j)}$ as follows: 
$$E_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k e_k(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n) x^k.$$ Now if we define the $k^{th}$ [power sum symmetric polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_sum_symmetric_polynomial) by 
$$p_k(x) := \sum_{i=1}^x x_i^k = \sum_{i=1}^x e^{k \cdot f(i)},$$ we typically can get expansions for the limiting cases of these products as
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} E_n(x) = \exp\left(\sum_{k \geq 1} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k} p_k(\infty) x^k\right),$$ formally at least, and when $x \mapsto 1$ provided suitable convergence conditions on the infinite products.

Now let's examine a slightly more general form of your first two series expressions (again, without immediate considerations of convergence for right now):
$$F_N(x) := \sum_{n \leq N} E_n(x) = N + \sum_{k=1}^{N} (N+1-k) (-1)^k e_k \cdot x^k.$$
Thus to evaluate these classes of series, we need to examine the limiting cases of 
the following equations as $N \rightarrow \infty$: 
$$\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \left[N + (N+1) (E_{N}(1)-1) + [w^N] \left(\sum_{i \geq 1} p_i(\infty) w^i\right) \exp\left(-\sum_{k \geq 1} p_k(\infty) \frac{w^k}{k}\right)\right].$$ This is not a full solution as the corresponding cases of the power sum polynomials, $p_k = \sum_{i \geq 1} e^{k \cdot f(i)}$, are difficult to sum in closed-form, but it should allow you to make some simplifications for special cases of the $f(i)$. For example, I was able to approximate some of these series in the special case of $f(i) := -i$ by making some asymptotic assumptions.